# Google Analytics Stopped Working after Ungradation to Magento 1.7

Tags: magento

Google Analytics stopped working as i upgrade the Magento 1.6 to Magento 1.7.

Really Stuck what to do, i have already

`reference name="after_body_start">
            <block type="googleanalytics/ga" name="google_analytics" as="google_analytics" template="googleanalytics/ga.phtml" />
        </reference>`

in my `googleanalytics.xml`

Not able to set it properly for Magento 1.7.

Comment: can you see GA code in you resulted page source?

Answer (score 2):

Add a tag `template="googleanalytics/ga.phtml"` in the `layout/googleanalytics.xml`

```
<layout version="0.1.0">

<!--
Default layout, loads most of the pages
-->

    <default>
        <!-- Mage_GoogleAnalytics -->
        <reference name="after_body_start">
            <block type="googleanalytics/ga" 
                   name="google_analytics"
                   as="google_analytics"
                   template="googleanalytics/ga.phtml" />
        </reference>
    </default>
</layout>
```